# How to apply html tags within a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that contains a string inside a  cell.

The string looks like this:

```
<p>Hello John!,<br><br>You're a really <b>good friend!</b></p>
```

How would I go about trying to make this text appear in the table without having the HTML tags appear as strings, and instead apply the HTML tags to the regular text as appropriate, so that the resulting text is:

```
Hello John!

You're a really good friend!
```

with `good friend!` bolded?

This string comes from an external database so I need to deal with these tags somehow and I can't work around it.

Comment: How did that string get into the table in the first place? Please show us enough of your “*[mcve]*” code that we can reproduce your problem and offer a practical answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `innerHTML` attribute of a specific html object.
For instance, you can solve the above issue like this :

```
let htmlString = "<p>Hello John!,<br><br>You're a really <b>good friend!</b></p>"
```

And let's say the table would like this :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id='cell-1'></td>
<td id='cell-2'></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In this case, you can inject the htmlString in to the `cell-1` like this :

```
document.getElementById('cell-1').innerHTML = htmlString
```

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this. This will remove all htmls.

```js
 let originalString = "<p>Hello John!,<br><br>You're a really <b>good friend!</b></p> ";
let strippedString = originalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "");
console.log(strippedString )
```

If you want to keep br tag and remove everything else then

```js
 let originalString = "<p>Hello John!,<br><br>You're a really <b>good friend!</b></p> ";
let strippedString = originalString.replace(/<(?!\s*br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/gi, "");
console.log(strippedString )
```

If you want to keep b and br tag and remove everything else then

```js
let originalString = "<p>Hello John!,<br><br>You're a really <b>good friend!</b></p> ";
let strippedString = originalString.replace(/<(?!\/*\s*[br|b]\s*\/?)[^>]+>/gi, "");
console.log(strippedString )
```

EDITED : If you want to keep some tags like br and b, you can also do. Add  with same logic

```js
 let html = "<p>Hello John!,<br><br>You're a really <b>good friend!</b></p> ";
  
   html = html.replace("<br>","||br||");  
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   html = tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
   console.log(html.replace("||br||","<br>"));
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because I need the html tags to be applied when appropriate e.g. I need the second sentence to break onto a new line and the "good friend!" to be bolded

Comment: @user11508332 check the last option, with the second option you can remove everything except br. Third option is a function, I have only shown how to remove keep br, you can keep any other tag you want.

Comment: @user11508332 I have updated the regex to /<(?!\/*\s*[br|b]\s*\/?)[^>]+>/gi      this will keep the bold and br